# Не могу сравнить значение ячейки LinkedList со строкой

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Имеется код:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    static LinkedList<Character> chars = new LinkedList<Character>();
    static LinkedList<String> strings = new LinkedList<>();
    static LinkedList<Integer> ints = new LinkedList<>();
    static LinkedList<String> intsName = new LinkedList<>();

    static boolean isOut = false;

    static boolean isInt = false;
    static boolean isIntName = false;
    static boolean isEq = false;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter path: ");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String path = scanner.nextLine();

        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            int c;
            while ((c = br.read()) != -1) {
                chars.add((char) c);
            }
            br.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            mainLg();
        }
    }
    public static void mainLg(){
        StringConv();
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++){

            if (strings.get(i).equals(" ")){

            } else if (isInt){
                intsName.add(strings.get(i));
                isInt = false;
                isIntName = true;
            } else if (isIntName){
                isEq = true;
                isIntName = false;
            } else if (isEq){
                ints.add(Integer.parseInt(strings.get(i)));
                isEq = false;
            } else if (isOut){
                isOut = false;
                Out(strings.get(i));
            }

            if (strings.get(i).equals("int")){
                isInt = true;
            }

            if (strings.get(i).equals("Out")){
                isOut = true;
            }
            System.out.println(strings.get(i));

        }


    }

    public static void StringConv(){
        String name = "";
         for (int i = 0; i < chars.size(); i++){
             if (chars.get(i) != ' ' && chars.get(i) != ';'){
                 name += chars.get(i);
             } else {
                 strings.add(name);
                 strings.add(" ");
                 name = "";
             }
         }
    }

    public static void Out(String x){
        for (int i = 0; i < intsName.size(); i++){
            if (intsName.get(i).equals(x)){
                System.out.println(ints.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Я считываю посимвольно текстовый документ в котором содержится это:

```
int h = 8755;
Out h;
```

И записываю каждый отдельн6ый символ в LinkedList chars. Затем с помощью метода StringConv преобразую символы chars в слова и каждое слово записываю в LinkedList strings.
Проблема заключается в том, что в методе mainLg когда я сравниваю значение ячейки LinkedList strings со строкой "Out", метод equals всегда возвращает false.
Если же выводить каждую ячейку strings, то можно заметить что строка out там присутствует.
[image: Строка Out присутствует!]

Но все равно метод equals возвращает false при сравнении ячейки strings и строки Out, хотя последняя там явно присутствует.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Глубоко не разбирался в Вашем коде, но Ваша проблема в том что строка содержит пробелы,  решится она если используете метод `trim()` http://proglang.su/java/strings-trim например, он грубо говоря убирает пробелы слева и справа строки, но не внутри самой строки.

```
if (strings.get(i).trim().equals("Out")){
                isOut = true;
            }
```

Или можно использовать метод `contains()` https://javahelp.online/osnovy/metod-contains-java он проверяется содержится ли подстрока в строке.

```
if (strings.get(i).contains("Out")){
                    isOut = true;
                }
```

Эти два решения решают последствия проблемы, а не саму проблему. Текущий механизм работы усложнен, могу порекомендовать использовать не посимвольное чтение, а построчное https://javadevblog.com/kak-postrochno-schity-vat-fajl-v-java.html. То есть у Вас будет список строк. Затем к каждой строке применить `split()` по пробелу https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/2907-metod-split-v-java-delim-stroku-na-chasti и в итоге у Вас будет список слов каждой строки.
Мне кажется это облегчит общий механизм, но конечно могу ошибаться.